# Calculated Column: Distinct id# should return first date and ignore other dates

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, calculated-columns

I have the requirement in which id# has duplicate records and also has duplicate received_date, where I need to show only unique received date for each id#. Could you please help me on how to resolve this?

Data sample shown below:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOYu3.png]

I have tried the following in the calculated column

```
expected_date_or_result =
VAR selected_id = test[id#]
VAR distinct_received_date =
    CALCULATE (
        FIRSTDATE ( test[received_date] ),
        FILTER ( test, test[id#] = selected_id )
    )
RETURN
    distinct_received_date
```

I am not sure now to add blanks in case of duplicate received_date.

Please help me with this.

**Note: I cannot use remove duplicate option since it is affecting my column group**

Comment: Not clear what you want as end result. Less rows of data? Blank replaced with firstdate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely many ways to approach this but here's the first one that comes to my mind:

```
expected_date_or_result =
VAR TopRow =
    TOPN (
        1,
        FILTER ( test, test[id#] = EARLIER ( test[id#] ) ),
        test[received_date], ASC,
        test[group], ASC
    )
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( TopRow, test[group] = EARLIER ( test[group] ) ),
        test[received_date]
    )
```

This picks the top row of the table filtered by `id#` and sorted by `received_date` and `group` and then filters that row so that it's only non-empty if the `group` is the top one and extracts the `received_date` column using `MAXX`.

[image: Result]

Comment: Actually, I am having move received date in "A" group as well

Comment: So you have fully duplicated rows?

Comment: Modified the screenshot in my question above, data also has few other columns associated with the column given.

Comment: Yes, I have duplicates as well, i need one id# one received date that is max received date

Comment: Add an index column then and use that column in place of `group` in my answer.